# How can I put data from the same column into separate columns with a group by?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

My data:

```
trial  name  quantity
1      sam   1
1      mary  9
2      bill  5
2      mary  2
```

Desired output:

```
name  1    2
sam   1    0
mary  9    2
bill  0    5
```

The "1" in the top row of the desired output indicates the first trial from the data, the "2" indicating the second trial.  Sam wasn't part of the second trial and Bill wasn't part of the first trial (we can see this from the data).  Sam and Mary were part of the first trial with quantities 1, 9.  Mary and Bill were part of the second trial with quantities 2, 5.

Assuming a large number of trials (100+), what query do I want to use to get my desired output?  I thought GROUP_CONCAT was what I wanted, but that doesn't seem to work well with 0-data.

Comment: Really confused how somebody could want this closed due to "unclear what you're asking" -- it's perfectly clear with the example.

Answer (score 2):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN trial = 1 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
    MAX(CASE WHEN trial = 2 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS '2'
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY name
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1a993/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: I have a very large # of trials -- is there another way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you could do it dynamically. I'm not really familiar with sqllite syntax.